# Retrieving Sensor data via Xbee

Tags: gpio, pi-3, serial, remote, xbee

I have 2 XBee radios, one works as a coordinator and one as a router. The coordinator is connected to my raspberry pi 3 and the router is connected to an analog temperature sensor (TMP36). I'm also using a python script to collect the sensor readings from my TMP36 and then transmitting it to the coordinator (via XBee router). *I need help setting up the serial port in the raspberry pi 3*, since I know that everything, regarding the setup of the serial ports for this new pi, changed. We are using X-CTU software (latest release) to configure the XBee radios, the radios are connected as follows:

**Xbee Coordinator:**

XBee 3.3 V port -----> RPI 3.3V

XBee GND ----------> RPI GND

XBee DOUT ---------> RPI UARTRX (GPIO 15)

XBee DIN -------------> RPI UARTTX (GPIO 14)

**XBee Router:**
The XBee is connected on the following DIGI Board:
http://ftp1.digi.com/support/documentation/xbibudev_referenceguide.pdf
and it has a TMP36 temperature sensor connected to DIO3 (pin 17)

Answer (score 1):

Found this [How do I make serial work on the Raspberry Pi3](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45570/how-do-i-make-serial-work-on-the-raspberry-pi3)

I've had success with the same xBee modules on all other variants of raspis, seems like you just need to adjust the /dev/ttyAMA0 to /dev/serial0